# Updating state before adding it to a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that updates a state object and adds it to a array-list.
The issue is that the State value can be changed from user-input and it adds the old value to the List, but if i click it a second time it's had time enough to update the State adds the correct value.

I believe that the state update needs to be executed before adding it to the list. How can this be done, and what is the best practice for solving this?

**My Function**

```
    const addObjectStateToList = () => {
        props.updateMeshState(); //Updating state
        setCart(currentState => [...currentState, props.meshObjectValues]); //Adding state to list
    }
```

**Function Usage**

```
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={addObjectStateToList }>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>
    )
```

Comment: Instead of manually calling set cart, subscribe to the state change event, and call set cart when that event emits. This assumes you're using redux. https://redux.js.org/api/store

Comment: Ty. i currently do not have Redux implemented in the project. I do use hooks though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) for updating the state depending on `meshObjectValues`

```
const addObjectStateToList = () => props.updateMeshState();

useEffect(() => {
  setCart(currentState => [...currentState, props.meshObjectValues]);
}, [props.meshObjectValues]);
```

Comment: It seems i might have been somewhat unclear, apologies. The state updates constantly and i want the current value of the state when the user presses the button.

Comment: Try making a reproducible example, you may use a reference and check the prev state before updating